# What is this regulators package ?

Tags: voltage-regulator, packages

I'm reverse engineering / hacking a Chinese board which has the footprint for this regulator which i want to replace. I am not quite sure what the package is though, I'm certain someone here does.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a D-Pak aka TO-252.

The [ST datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d7/5f/dc/5c/d5/b6/48/7c/CD00000447.pdf/files/CD00000447.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000447.pdf) for 78M05 shows this as a standard package for this part.

Comment: Hard to beat the speed of Photons :D

Comment: +1 That's not an ST part though, it's a domestic manufacturer.

Comment: yup, it's not ST.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, obviously it's better to use the datasheet from the specific manufacturer if you know what it is. But if you don't, for jelly bean parts like this, the low cost vendors will be duplicating the designs of bigger companies like ST/TI/On/... and will match the package very closely.

Comment: @ThePhoton Absolutely, and it's more than justified in this case, but worth keeping in mind especially when the congruence may be sketchy to the point where words like 'counterfeit' come to mind. Like some of the "National" switching regulator chips that come from China. I have bought parts from this particular maker and they're okay in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [D-PAK (TO-252AA)](https://www.vishay.com/docs/95016/dpak252a.pdf)

Dimension **E** should be 6.5mm, and **e** ~2.3mm

[image]